# Using count() = 0 in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run the following query but get an error:

```
select S 
from St
where  count(

    select *
    from L
    where L.Wh = S

) = 0
```

I get the error:

> error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax...

How can I write this query?

Comment: You better explained what you need *by words*, because right now one of the possible answers to "How can I fix this?" is - "replace it with `SELECT S FROM St`"

Comment: @zerkms I understand the `code` rather than plain `English` as English is not my native tongue :-)

Comment: @Mithun: it's possible to get it, indeed. But the thing is - that usually wrong query isn't that helpful (and may even lead to a wrong answers), so it's a good idea to add a text description as well. And I hope OP will do that next time. PS: it's not even close to my native language as well ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
SELECT S
FROM ST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (    
  SELECT *
  FROM L
  WHERE L.Wh = ST.S
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the COUNT aggregate function inside the subselect, so your subquery returns a single result.

```
select S 
from St
where (select COUNT(*)
       from L
       where L.Wh = St.S
      ) = 0
```

If you want to select all the records in "St" who don't have any records in "L", you can also use the `NOT EXISTS()` function:

```
SELECT S
FROM St
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM L WHERE L.Wh = St.S)
```

Comment: You probably have to add the table name as prefix; otherwise he might not know where to get the "S" from. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 select s from st
   where (select count(*) from L where l.wh=s)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using a `join`:

```
select S from St
left join L on St.S = L.Wh
where L.Wh is null
```

Working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3c23/2

Personally, I usually prefer joins, but yet another option is using `not in`:

```
select S from St
where S not in (select Wh from L)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3c23/3